# can't open nano editor - "illegal instruction"

Tags: raspbian-buster, nano

/etc/os-release says raspbian 10 (buster)

pi 3

i know this worked previously, because i originally set up the whole pi using nano. but now, every time i open nano, any file, no file, sudo, or not, i get "illegal instruction" and nothing else. i have uninstalled and reinstalled nano with

sudo apt-get remove nano

sudo apt-get install nano

nano --version says 3.2

behavior persists.

Comment: what's the output of `ldd /bin/nano`

Comment: This may [solve your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65631801/illegal-instructioncore-dumped-error-on-jetson-nano)

Comment: can't figure out how to make this readable with line breaks

'/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v6l.so (0xb6efb000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1 (0xb6ed0000)
libncursesw.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libncursesw.so.6 (0xb6e93000)
libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtinfo.so.6 (0xb6e62000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6d14000)
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f0e000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 (0xb6d01000)`